# Как верстаются такие блоки?

Tags: html, css

Есть такой блок, который нужно сверстать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обычно верстаются такие блоки? Если делать простую резиновую верстку, то при изменении разрешения экрана высота картинки в широком блоке будет уменьшаться и будет меньше по высоте. Как верстаются такие блоки, чтобы высота картинок была одинаковая при изменении ширины экрана?

Comment: Можно попробовать задать картинкам фиксированную высоту, которую будете менять на определенных разрешениях. И так же задать картинкам свойства `object-fit: cover;` и `object-position: 50% 50%;`

Comment: Grid пробовали?

Comment: Как написано выше - object-fit: cover; width: auto; height: 100%; А родителю изображения думаю ещё нужно задать display: flex; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden; но это не точно))